# Magento Custom Module Helper Not Found

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create system configuration for my module.After adding system.xml I'm getting

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Training_Banners_Helper_Data' not found

magento/app/code/local/Training/Banners/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class Training_Banners_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Training_Banners>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Training_Banners>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <banners>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Training_Banners</module>
                    <frontName>banners</frontName>
                </args>
            </banners>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <banners> 
                    <file>banners.xml</file>
                </banners>
            </updates>
        </layout>   
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <banners after="Mage_Adminhtml">Training_Banners_Adminhtml</banners>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <banners>
                    <file>training_banners.xml</file>
                </banners>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <banners>
                <class>Training_Banners_Block</class>
            </banners>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <banners>  
                <class>Training_Banners_Helper</class>
            </banners>
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <banners>
                <class>Training_Banners_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>banners_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </banners>
            <banners_mysql4>
                <class>Training_Banners_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <manage>
                        <table>banners</table>
                    </manage>
                </entities>
            </banners_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <banners_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </banners_read>
            <banners_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </banners_write>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Please post some more code and information, so that we can help you. E.g. paths to the files, whole content of config.xml, content of Helper_Data class etc.

Comment: @Simon: Added full code.

Comment: Please also post the system.xml. :-) Maybe you use a `module="sometag"` for a translation tag there instead of `module="banners"`...

Comment: I removed system.xml file.Even after system->config throwing this error

Comment: After removing `system.xml` make sure your cache is cleared.
Do you invoke somewhere in code this helper ? If yes how do you do it (paste code pls)?
Please paste `system.xml` file content.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using "banners" group name as another module group name.So there was a conflict.

Comment: Thanks for posting back, that's a pretty obscure error.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, Create folder `Helper` in your module.
Then create File `Data.php` in it.
File content should contain:

```
class Company_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{}
```

that is enough to solve your issue.
FYI: This happens cause magento is trying to translate content of your  tags. Translation is handlend using `__()` method of module helper.

Comment: Data.php present under Helper directory.Don't know why this error coming!

Comment: it might be your misstypo. Check config, class names, folder names